# Python, xml.dom, and parsing

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, xmldom

I currently have an XML file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<max:CreateMXCLASSIFICATION xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/max">
  <max:MXCLASSIFICATIONSet>
    <max:CLASSSTRUCTURE>
      <max:MAXINTERRORMSG>string</max:MAXINTERRORMSG>
      <max:CLASSSTRUCTUREID>string</max:CLASSSTRUCTUREID>
      <max:CLASSSPEC action="AddChange">
        <max:ASSETATTRID>string</max:ASSETATTRID>
        <max:ORGID>string</max:ORGID>
        <max:SECTION>string</max:SECTION>
        <max:SITEID>string</max:SITEID>
        <max:CLASSSPECUSEWITH action="AddChange">
          <max:OBJECTNAME1>string</max:OBJECTNAME1>
        </max:CLASSSPECUSEWITH>
      </max:CLASSSPEC>
      <max:CLASSUSEWITH action="Replace">
        <max:OBJECTNAME2>string</max:OBJECTNAME2>
      </max:CLASSUSEWITH>
    </max:CLASSSTRUCTURE>
  </max:MXCLASSIFICATIONSet>
</max:CreateMXCLASSIFICATION>
```

I am trying to extract the structure to create a dictionary, however right now the following code has an error in logic that I cannot spot. Currently when rChild gets reassigned a NodeList of children and continues to iterate through it does not check the childNodes of the following elements:

```
    <max:ASSETATTRID>string</max:ASSETATTRID>
    <max:ORGID>string</max:ORGID>
    <max:SECTION>string</max:SECTION>
    <max:SITEID>string</max:SITEID>
    <max:CLASSSPECUSEWITH action="AddChange">
```

Here is the code that I am using:

```
rChild = root.childNodes
for x in range(7):
    for y in rChild:
        if y.localName is not None:
            rChild = y.childNodes
            print rChild
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: "the following code has an error in logic that I cannot spot" What happens? Do you get an error method? No output?

Comment: It complies and runs, it simply, "does not check the childNodes of the following elements:" ASSETATTRID, ORGID, SECTION, SITEID, CLASSSPECUSEWITH, So therefore, OBJECTNAME1 is never found.